# Case insensitive queries for Tridion and Oracle DB as Broker DB

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, oracle

When we are using SQL server and executing broker queries (Tridion Content Delivery API) the results returned are case insensitive.

However while doing same with ORACLE DB results returned are case sensitive.

We want results to be case insensitive. Could  you please help us on below points?

- Since our DB is shared by other applications, is there a way that we can have some setting at instance level only?
- Would we need to install any patch to return results as case insensitive?

Please suggest what normally is done in case we use ORACLE as a DB and need case insensitive results.

We are using  following settings :

- Content Delivery Server : Windows server 2008 R2 64-Bit
- CMS : Tridion 2011SP1
- Broker Database: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit 
  PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 
  CORE 11.2.0.2.0

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with Tridion, as that is the expected behavior of your database... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425153/reason-why-oracle-is-case-sensitive

Comment: Hi Nuno, Yes I agree this should be to do with DB, but I am wondering if something can be done at tridion level so that every query we do returns results as case insensitive.

Comment: Maybe someone will know it - I don't think our software changes that behavior from any DB, at most you may be able to change the Oracle configuration to allow for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using API queries, or are you querying the database directly?  Do you have some examples?

Have you checked with your Oracle DBA as well for possible solutions?

Here is another post which can give you a sense of several possible workarounds from a database standpoint:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391069/case-insensitive-searching-in-oracle

Comment: Hi Elena,We are using API Qeuries. Our DBA has suggested to Use Alter System for parameters NLS_COMP and NLS_SORT.